# ¿Como puedo imprimir una cantidad n de espacios a la derecha con printf?

Tags: bash, shell, printf

Quiero alinear un texto, por ejemplo digamos que quiero tener 12 espacios a la derecha antes de el texto. Intente con esto pero me sale alineado a la izquierda y no a la derecha:

```sh
printf "%12s" "texto" #-->
#            texto
```

¿Como puedo obtener algo así?:

```
#                                                                       texto
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Llena con espacios tantas columnas tenga la terminal menos 12:

```
printf "%*s\n" $(($(tput cols)-12)) "texto"
```

Usando dos evaluaciones: una para obtener el número de columnas y otra para la resta.

Comment: Gracias, pero ¿que significa el asterisco dentro de "%*s\n"?

Comment: Es un marcador especial para recibir el número de caracteres.

Answer (score 2):

También podés crear una función que repita la llamada a *printf*.

No creo que sea la mejor solución, pero al menos es otra:

```
$ repetir() { char="$1"; times="$2"; for i in $(seq 1 $times); do printf "$char"; done }
$ echo "$(repetir "=" 2)" hola
== hola
```